# Understanding Null handling in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

I have an Entity Framework query that contains the following line.

```
let company = pc.Contact.CompaniesContacts.FirstOrDefault().Company
```

If you do something like this directly in SQL and `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`, then the result of the entire expression will be `null`. (I.e., `company` will be `null`.)

But in Entity Framework, if the `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`, then I get a null-reference exception.

Is there any way to have Entity Framework behave more like SQL here?

Comment: please post an example SQL query showing the company getting filled in as null when there's no rows in the result.

Comment: @Jasmine: It would take me a while to get that in SQL. I have never seen any type of null-reference error in SQL Server. Are you suggesting they can exist?

Comment: No I'm suggesting that it doesn't exist. A result with no rows doesn't return any values for any columns, so it's incorrect to say that "company" would be null after such a query. Thus, EF is handling it correctly - it is preventing you from obtaining a value from a meaningless query result. If you want to have a default value, you must provide it - which IMO, is the correct behavior. Hamlet's answer below is correct

Comment: @Jasmine: You can have a calculated column that uses this type of expression, and it's possible that since there are no matching rows in the expression, the column becomes null.

Comment: No it doesn't. Even with a calculated column, aggregate expression, or column-with-default, you still get nothing if the query returns zero rows, unless what you mean by calculated column is "we provided a value for the zero-row situation" in which case that's Hamlet's answer. If you are talking about the situation where an expression is selected as part of a row, and one of the operands of that expression is null, but the output is non-null - that's a database setting or a characteristic of the expression itself. Try *select null + 'someString'* on your server to find out what your setting is

Comment: @Jasmine: SQL isn't my greatest strength, and obviously SQL has no `let` statement, so it's kind of like comparing apples and oranges. In your last suggestion, the result I get is `NULL`, which is what I would expect. The point is, SQL propogates `NULL` this way when any portion of the input is `NULL`. Entity Framework throws an exception. Since Entity Framework executes as SQL, I was hoping I could just propagate the `NULL`s.

Comment: EF creates SQL to get entities from the database, but that's not the same thing, it's a separate step. If the generated SQL query returns no rows, and then you ask for the first row, the only reasonable result is null. If you then ask for something to be looked up from that row that doesn't exist, the only reasonable result is to throw an error, which is what the EF does. The reason I asked for SQL code is because you're thinking of some SQL statement that doesn't map to the EF operation you are attempting. If you could post that SQL statement, we might be able to give you the EF for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
let company = pc.Contact.CompaniesContacts.FirstOrDefault() != null
             ? pc.Contact.CompaniesContacts.FirstOrDefault().Company
             : null
```

Comment: Gawd, I hope the SQL version of that would be more efficient than the C# version.

Comment: If you will provide the query maybe would be more efficient way to achieve what you want.